# Debugging Access SQL

Tags: sql, debugging, ms-access

I have this query in access but it doesn't return any result when I use the Like function. It does return result when I set it to equal to.

```
Select * from myTable where name like "*Al#pp*"
```

note that the # sign is part of the spelling to lookup and not a wildcard, but I think access is taking it as a wildcard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `#` is not supposed to be a wildcard then you have to escape it. Try:

```
Select * from myTable where name like "*Al[#]pp*"
```

Comment: okay. that will work when I spell the lookup word. What if I have it as an input that allows the user to type what they want to lookup?

Comment: Use something like: `Replace(SearchValue, "#", "[#]")`.

Comment: If your string is going to contain wildcards, you can use the `InStr` function to test if a string contains another string instead. That way you don't have to worry about them at all.